# ASP.NET: How do I create a GridView with dynamic rows with 2 dropdownlists?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

The two ddl get populated from the database, the population of the second dropdownlist depends on the value selected in the first ddl.

For example: You have can choose an umbrella for the first ddl (umbrella is one of the items in the catalog table in the DB) and the second dropdownlist will be populated with the different colors of umbrellas available (also from the DB).

Additionally the GridView must allow rows to be added dynamically.

One more requirement: The user can create all the rows needed first before selecting the values in the ddl.

I have tried doing this on my own and have hit the wall multiple times and was wondering if someone else has done this before.

I am using: Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2008

Comment: I had done same thing by Refering [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Adding-Dynamic-Rows-in-GridView-with-DropDownLists-in-ASP.Net.aspx)

Comment: how your gridview will be bind to data? what will be datasource, is it List<> or DataTable or anything else?

Comment: Everything is in the link just open and see.Datasource will be DataTable as per the Example in the link